# Please help recovering lost volume group

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, lvm, data-recovery

After a reboot, the volume group on my server completely disappeared.

```
[root@dal01 log]# vgdisplay
No volume groups found

[root@dal01 /]# lvdisplay
No volume groups found

[root@dal01 ~]# pvdisplay (pvdisplay displays nothing)

[root@dal01 log]# df -h
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1 97G 72G 21G 78% /
tmpfs 12G 0 12G 0% /dev/shm

[root@dal01 vg_dal01]# sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="92622347-3d12-4f02-bc38-093eba3e607b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="EUBjbv-JVpH-6QLv-yAxX-dopZ-CDHg-BOcpXa" TYPE="LVM2_member" 

[root@dal01 log]# fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 4000.0 GB, 3999977701376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486302 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 1 267350 2147483647+ ee GPT
[root@dal01 log]#
```

vgcfgrestore says this:

```
[root@dal01 backup]# vgcfgrestore vg_dal01
  Couldn't find device with uuid EUBjbv-JVpH-6QLv-yAxX-dopZ-CDHg-BOcpXa.
  Cannot restore Volume Group vg_dal01 with 1 PVs marked as missing.
  Restore failed.
```

There's still a backup:

```
[root@dal01 backup]# cat /etc/lvm/backup/vg_dal01
# Generated by LVM2 version 2.02.100(2)-RHEL6 (2013-10-23): Wed Dec 11 01:56:09 2013

contents = "Text Format Volume Group"
version = 1

description = "Created *after* executing 'lvcreate -n kvm109_img_4 --size 5120m vg_dal01'"

creation_host = "myserver"      # Linux myserver 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 22 00:31:26 UTC 2013 x86_64
creation_time = 1386744969      # Wed Dec 11 01:56:09 2013

vg_dal01 {
id = "hahYN8-jcKS-sSVi-RAcp-lOSh-0Mfl-gerfKs"
seqno = 21
format = "lvm2" # informational
status = ["RESIZEABLE", "READ", "WRITE"]
flags = []
extent_size = 65536      # 32 Megabytes
max_lv = 0
max_pv = 0
metadata_copies = 0

physical_volumes {

pv0 {
id = "EUBjbv-JVpH-6QLv-yAxX-dopZ-CDHg-BOcpXa"
device = "/dev/sda3"    # Hint only

status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
flags = []
dev_size = 7573082112   # 3.52649 Terabytes
pe_start = 2048
pe_count = 115556       # 3.52649 Terabytes
}
}

logical_volumes {

kvm102_img {
id = "dzpPcD-Dw31-fYDV-8OTv-YuX4-HWK1-mWnKR8"
status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
flags = []
creation_host = "myserver"
creation_time = 1384023518      # 2013-11-09 13:58:38 -0500
segment_count = 1

segment1 {
start_extent = 0
extent_count = 3200     # 100 Gigabytes

type = "striped"
stripe_count = 1        # linear

stripes = [
"pv0", 0
]
}
}

kvm108_img {
id = "odqzve-SWLr-pKsH-4Qj4-lflF-mFBn-6l6Lu3"
status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
flags = []
creation_host = "myserver"
creation_time = 1384086241      # 2013-11-10 07:24:01 -0500
segment_count = 1

segment1 {
start_extent = 0
extent_count = 6400     # 200 Gigabytes

type = "striped"
stripe_count = 1        # linear

stripes = [
"pv0", 3200
]
}
}

kvm109_img {
id = "RBTo23-NOq2-rcI1-slnN-jYeM-rHZu-IYzR4T"
status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
flags = []
creation_host = "myserver"
creation_time = 1384122997      # 2013-11-10 17:36:37 -0500
segment_count = 1

segment1 {
start_extent = 0
extent_count = 320      # 10 Gigabytes

type = "striped"
stripe_count = 1        # linear

stripes = [
"pv0", 9600
]
}
}

kvm110_img {
id = "op2Hez-UiDs-Nm6M-OuI6-1uaJ-cc9H-jJDH4q"
status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
flags = []
creation_host = "myserver"
creation_time = 1385452338      # 2013-11-26 02:52:18 -0500
segment_count = 1

segment1 {
start_extent = 0
extent_count = 27200    # 850 Gigabytes

type = "striped"
stripe_count = 1        # linear

stripes = [
"pv0", 9920
]
}
}

kvm110_img_3 {
id = "Zsm1Yj-QrZH-okcf-KhF6-ic1M-tNpF-jrA3Sh"
status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
flags = []
creation_host = "myserver"
creation_time = 1386744381      # 2013-12-11 01:46:21 -0500
segment_count = 1

segment1 {
start_extent = 0
extent_count = 12800    # 400 Gigabytes

type = "striped"
stripe_count = 1        # linear

stripes = [
"pv0", 37120
]
}
}

kvm109_img_4 {
id = "w98qm2-0pK0-xjW4-1lyj-UNP0-xc1F-FeeSVK"
status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
flags = []
creation_host = "myserver"
creation_time = 1386744969      # 2013-12-11 01:56:09 -0500
segment_count = 1

segment1 {
start_extent = 0
extent_count = 160      # 5 Gigabytes

type = "striped"
stripe_count = 1        # linear

stripes = [
"pv0", 49920
]
}
}
}
}
```

However I want to make sure that I can still recover it without messing it up even more.

I found this link: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/mdatarecover.html but I'm not sure it is the way to go.

Anybody care to help, please?

UPDATE: Partition table:

```
[root@dal01 ~]# parted -l
Model: AMCC 9650SE-4LP DISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 4000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  107GB   107GB   ext4               boot
 2      107GB   125GB   17.2GB
 3      125GB   4000GB  3875GB                     lvm
```

UPDATE2: I managed to recover the volume group, but all the LVM seem corrupted.

```
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  107GB   107GB   ext4               boot
 2      107GB   125GB   17.2GB
 3      125GB   4000GB  3875GB                     lvm


Error: /dev/mapper/vg_dal01-kvm102_img: unrecognised disk label           

Error: /dev/mapper/vg_dal01-kvm108_img: unrecognised disk label           

Error: /dev/mapper/vg_dal01-kvm110_img: unrecognised disk label           

Error: /dev/mapper/vg_dal01-kvm119: unrecognised disk label 

Error: /dev/mapper/vg_dal01-kvm110_img_3: unrecognised disk label         

Error: /dev/mapper/vg_dal01-kvm109_img: unrecognised disk label
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: All your volumes seem to be present. What makes you think they're corrupted?

Comment: I can't boot them. The partitions seem to be gone. I am using testdisk right now to see if I can recover them. Any other suggestion?